# Python matching elements in lists of lists and combining into a single set

Tags: python-3.x, list, matching

I have data where I've stored a set of values in lists in a list. These lists will contain mostly unique data, however one element is guaranteed to be the same as one element in another of the lists. What I'm looking to do is iterate over those lists (no set total number of lists), match two nested lists using the shared element and then combine these two lists. This would need to be done for every list in the list.

Example:

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, Hello], [5, 6, 7, 8, Hello], 
          [9, 10, 11, 12, Bye], [13, 14, 15, 16, Bye], 
          [17, 18, 19, 20, Python], [21, 22, 23, 24, Python]]
```

Desired result:

```
my_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, Hello, 5, 6, 7, 8, Hello]
my_list2 = [9, 10, 11, 12, Bye, 13, 14, 15, 16, Bye]
my_list3 = [17, 18, 19, 20, Python, 21, 22, 23, 24, Python]
....
```

In this case they will have matched on Hello, Bye and Python. The matching lists don't necessarily immediatelly follow each other.

I've found some ways to search within list of lists for matching elements but they seem to be looking and pulling the shared element and I can't find a way to merge two sets once found.

I'm fairly new to Python so although I know what I would like it to do I don't know if I'm going down the right path and if Python has the functionality to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Edit: 
It will always be the last element in each list that is the matching value, the lists will always be structured in this format and not random

Comment: Yes, I've set the value collection so the last element will always be the one matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4, "Hello"], [5, 6, 7, 8, "Hello"], 
          [9, 10, 11, 12, "Bye"], [13, 14, 15, 16, "Bye"], 
          [17, 18, 19, 20, "Python"], [21, 22, 23, 24, "Python"]]
```

---

**Faster way by @JonClements:**

```
d = {} 
for lst in my_list: 
    d.setdefault(lst[-1], []).extend(lst)    

print(d.values)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

- `dictionary.setDefault(key,defaultValueIfKeyNotPresent)` returns the keys value if already present in the dictionary, else creates the key with the given
- `defaultValueIfKeyNotPresent` (or `None` if not explicitly given).  `.extend(lst)` is a conveniencemethod on lists that extends the list by some other iterable.

He also proposes another way with itertools and lambda - see comments.

---

**My step by step way:**

```
results = []
for n in set(x[-1] for x in my_list): # just get all last elements as set
    sameLastElement = [x for x in my_list if x[-1] == n] # get all sublists that match
    same = [] # accumulate sub lists into one list
    for a in sameLastElement:
        same +=  a
    results.append(same) # put into result array

print (results) # done
```

Output - had to change the last element to string:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 'Hello', 5, 6, 7, 8, 'Hello'], 
 [9, 10, 11, 12, 'Bye', 13, 14, 15, 16, 'Bye'], 
 [17, 18, 19, 20, 'Python', 21, 22, 23, 24, 'Python']]
```

You can deconstruct this`result` if you know how many will be in there, or simply iterate over all merged sublists.

```
list_a, list_b, list_c = results
```

or

```
for n in results:
    # do smth with each single merged list
```

Comment: That's brilliant! Works exaclty as I needed it. Thank you!

Comment: Or - make use of itertools.... `from itertools import groupby, chain; results = [list(chain.from_iterable(g)) for k, g in groupby(my_list, lambda L: L[-1])]`

Comment: Although, it'd make more sense to have them as a dictionary... `d = {}; for lst in my_list: d.setdefault(lst[-1], []).extend(lst)` - then d will have keys of the variable used to merge and the values will be the concatenated lists... also there'll be no need for them to be in order of the last element of each list.

Comment: @JonClements looking up the setdefault - that looks neat https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: @PatrickArtner I understand most of what's there, just curious about the x[-1] as it's not something I've come across, is this referring to the last element and in my case, with fixed list sizes, would x[4] have worked exactly the same?

Comment: @Patrick it'll probably also make sense to `.extend(lst[:-1])` to remove the grouping key from the values, so the `dict` would be like `{'Bye': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16']...}` then the values are perhaps more useful, plus the keys will be what would have been there... Depends what the OP wants though.

Comment: @Meshi a negative index is equivalent to `len(obj) - index`... so for an object of length 4, an index of `obj[-1]` is the same as `obj[3]`

Comment: It's doubtful that order is needed here... for the dict approach, the lists will be concat'd in the order they appear originally in my_list, but since we're moving from a list of lists and to a key/value system, the order isn't that relevant as they're accessible by key... Being able to access `d['Bye']` is more useful than having 3 lists of which you don't know which elements it had without scanning or the list or heavily relying on ordering to start with.